# How can I make sure that this function handles errors properly?

Tags: javascript, express, error-handling

I have a function that checks user input in an express application. I don't want to use any library to validate those inputs so I declared an array where errors are pushed into.

I have embedded the middleware function as a static method in a class...

```
static postAdchecker(req, res, next) {
        let { state, price, manufacturer, model, bodytype } = req.body;
        console.log('req', req.body);
         const errors = [];

         // If state is empty or undefined throw this error
         if (!state) {
             console.log('state', state);
             const error = {
                 message: 'Please specify the state of the car'
             };
             errors.push(error);
         }

         // If state is supplied, convert it to lowercase, trim and check if value is new/used
         if (state.toLowerCase().trim() !== 'new' && state.toLowerCase().trim() !== 'used') {
            const error = {
                message: 'State can only be new or used'
            };
            errors.push(error);
        }

        // Same goes for the others.
        if (!price) {
            const error = {
                message: 'You will need to specify a sale price'
            };
            errors.push(error);
        }

        if (!manufacturer) {
            const error = {
                message: 'Specify a manufacturer'
            };
            errors.push(error);
        }

        if (!model) {
            const error = {
                message: 'Specify a model'
            };
            errors.push(error);
        }

        if (!bodytype) {
            const error = {
                message: 'You will need to specify a bodytype'
            };
            errors.push(error);
        }

        return res.status(400).json({
            status: 400,
            errors: { 
                body: errors.map(err => err.message) 
               }
        });

         console.log('errors', errors);
         req.body.state = state.toLowerCase().trim();
         req.body.price = price.toLowerCase().trim();
         req.body.manufacturer = manufacturer.toLowerCase().trim();
         req.body.model = model.toLowerCase().trim();
         req.body.bodytype = bodytype.toLowerCase().trim();
         // req.authData;
         return next(); 

     }
```

How can I achieve the following?

- Convert the values in the input field to lowercase and trim when supplied.
- When there are errors, return all the errors.
- When there are no errors, transfer operation to the next function instead of returning an empty array.

Comment: Time for unit tests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing one condition:

```
 if(errors.length) { // <<<
   return res.status(400).json({
        status: 400,
        errors: { 
            body: errors.map(err => err.message) 
           }
      });
}
```

Comment: let me try that out

Comment: I think that hook fixed it. It should be ```errors.length``` though not ```err```. Thanks a lot